# how to upload binary files using ftp in c#

Tags: c#, ftp, binaryfiles

looking for a C# sample on how to upload binary files using ftp
thanks ?
am using VC2013 if it matters.my main problem is how to convert my loal file to binary and then ftp it.

Comment: You don't "convert" the file to binary. Instead just use FtpWebRequest if you only have one file to transfer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WebClient` class:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.UploadFile("ftp://host/path/to/the/file", @"C:\path\to\the\file");
}
```

If the server requires authentication, set the `Credentials` property:

```
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

Comment: thanks Thomas. when i download my zip file to my local pc I cannot unzip the file, "not recognized".

Comment: I did upload the zip file first.

Comment: @ramnz, did you upload from code, then download using an FTP client program? or both from code?

Comment: @ramnz, I just tried it, and I didn't reproduce the issue. Did you check that the downloaded file was identical to the original?

Comment: from code the upload, then filezillfila the download..... sizes are different, am trying to upload a zip, does this matter?

Comment: @ramnz, no, it doesn't matter, if you're transferring in binary mode. It is the default mode for WebClient; make sure you're using binary transfer in FileZilla as well.

Comment: thank you thomas got it to work using FtpWebRequest for now. here is how  string PureFileName = new FileInfo(fileName).Name;
        String uploadUrl = String.Format("{0}{1}/{2}", FtpUrl,UploadDirectory,PureFileName);
        FtpWebRequest req = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(uploadUrl);
        req.Proxy = null;
        req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName,password);
        req.UseBinary = true;
        req.UsePassive = true;